Blender Hair - get (automatically) material from parent object
I struggle to assign automatically the material from parent object to my hair setup. If possible i want to avoid using assign material node and get the material from parent object.
How to set it up?


You can assign the material of the Hair Geometry to the Curves object in the material list. Then you don't need a geometry node to set it. (But I'm not sure if this is considered "automatic".)

Actually this doesn't work. At least on my side.

I tried with the default cube & quick fur (Blender 4.2), replaced the fur material with the cube's material in the curves' material list. Then the fur was as red as the cube.

ah i see, when using the quick fur it works but i want to save my setup as asset so i guess i have to use empty hair and use my setup as modifier which uses "generate hair curve" modifier to avoid painting curve guidelines.

any idea how material assignment works when using "generate hair curves" on "emtpy hair"

The Generate Hair Curves node has a setting for the material which lets you define the hair material. Have you used this?
